# Remove fingers from video of phone manipulation

Tags: video, video-editing

I have a video camera filming my phone from above. I record a video showing some software manipulation on the phone.

I need a program that can remove my fingers when I change phone menu on video. When finished the video, we shouldn't see any finger or hand. How can we do that?

Maybe I can select my fingers as a layer and set opacity? Is it possible with a good video edit program?

Comment: To clarify, you have a video camera filming your phone from above, right?

Comment: If you have an android phone that's running marshmellow, and a windows 10 system, screencasting works from the phone to your PC. You'd need to capture that on the PC somehow though

Comment: Yes @NicolasRaoul, I need to filming my phone from above.

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to not use screencasting? (record phone screen to PC via USB)

Comment: Actually phone was a sample. I need to filming a smart watch and unfortunately it hasn't android.

Answer (score 2):

Traditionally this is done through a technique called Green Screening you would wear gloves of a given colour and the software would replace anything of that colour with the background from previous shots - but a) you would need to wear the gloves & b) the changes to the screen would not show until you moved your hands out of the way.

You could take an alternative approach by using a product such as [Mobizen](https://www.mobizen.com/).  This consists of an application on your phone and on your PC which allows you to either screen record on your PC what is happening on your phone or control your phone using your PCs mouse & keyboard while videoing the phones screen. Then of course you have no fingers in the shot to remove.  A video of this in action is available [here](https://youtu.be/qdepDY3ynxg).

Connection to the mobile is via USB, WiFi or Web.

Comment: Thank you Steve, I'll try these methods and write here tonight.

Comment: Technically My hand is closed phone's screen. In this case I couldn't see whole part of screen.

Comment: @Erdogan - If you are trying green screening then you will have to move your hand completely out of shot between actions. If you are remote controlling the phone your hand should never be in shot.